# Replace None value in list?

Tags: python, list, replace

I have:

```
d = [1,'q','3', None, 'temp']
```

I want to replace None value to 'None' or any string

expected effect:

```
d = [1,'q','3', 'None', 'temp']
```

a try replace in string and for loop but I get error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: If you need to turn `None` into a string for whatever you're doing next (that expects a character buffer object), why don't you need to turn the `1` into a string as well?

Comment: You may want to take a step back and consider how the list is built in the first place.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
['None' if v is None else v for v in d]
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = [1,'q','3', None, 'temp']
>>> ['None' if v is None else v for v in d]
[1, 'q', '3', 'None', 'temp']
```

Note the `is None` test to match the `None` singleton.

Comment: Just a note to reader in case it's not obvious that this creates a new list - it doesn't modify the existing list `d`.

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use `map` and convert **all items** to strings using the `str` function:

```
map(str, d)
#['1', 'q', '3', 'None', 'temp']
```

If you only want to convert the `None` values, you can do:

```
[str(di) if di is None else di for di in d]
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting Python 3.6 you can do it in shorter form:

```
d = [f'{e}' for e in d]
```

hope this helps to someone since, I was having this issue just a while ago.

Comment: what does f'{e}' mean here?

Comment: It's an "f-string" - Literal string interpolation. You can check more about it in [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). It's worth a while of reading because it's great feature.

Answer (score 3):

Using a *lengthy and inefficient however beginner friendly* for loop it would look like:

```
d = [1,'q','3', None, 'temp']
e = []

for i in d:
    if i is None: #if i == None is also valid but slower and not recommended by PEP8
        e.append("None")
    else:
        e.append(i)

d = e
print d
#[1, 'q', '3', 'None', 'temp']
```

*Only for beginners, @Martins answer is more suitable in means of power and efficiency*

Comment: Don't use `== None`; `None` is a singleton, using `is None` is faster and more pythonic and PEP-8 compliant.

Comment: Always use `is None` if that is what you mean. `i` can be a type that implements comparison to `None` as `True`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is means by `singleton` ?

Comment: An object of which there is only *one* copy during the lifetime of the program. `None`, `True`, `False`, `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` are all singletons part of Python itself.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is the right way to go, but in case, for reasons best known to you, you would rather replace it in-place rather than creating a new list (arguing the fact that python list is mutable), an alternate approach is as follows

```
d = [1,'q','3', None, 'temp', None]
try:
    while True:
        d[d.index(None)] = 'None'
except ValueError:
    pass

>>> d
[1, 'q', '3', 'None', 'temp', 'None']
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not notice any answer using lambda..

Someone who wants to use lambda....(Look into comments for explanation.)

```
#INPUT DATA
d =[1,'q','3', None, 'temp']

#LAMBDA TO BE APPLIED
convertItem = lambda i : i or 'None' 

#APPLY LAMBDA
res = [convertItem(i) for i in d]

#PRINT OUT TO TEST
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to match for `None` and replace it.

```py
def fixlist(l: list):
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if v is None:
            l[i] = 0
```